# Kurento Media Server 6.4 Terminating With Permissions Error

Tags: kurento

I have KMS installed on a locked-down server and it seems like there are permissions issues keeping it from running.

Whenever I try to run the service, I get the following error in `media-server_error.log`:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::filesystem::filesystem_error'
  what():  boost::filesystem::create_directory: Permission denied: "/var/log/kurento-media-server/logs"
```

I'm not sure why there's a permissions error, as kurento:root owns `/var/log/kurento-media-server`, my user is part of the root group, and the directory has 777 permissions.

Even if I create the directory manually with open permissions I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user that executes kurento-media-server has been changed recently to `kurento`. Try giving permission to that user on `/var/log/kurento-media-server/` and `/var/log/kurento-media-server/logs`. To do so, just execute:

```
sudo chown -R kurento /var/log/kurento-media-server/
```

**Edit:**

You should also check that `/var/log` directory has proper permissions to let user `kurento` access `/var/log/kurento-media-server/`.

Comment: Both of those directories are owned by `kurento` and both have open permissions (777).

Comment: Is `kurento-media-server` running as `kurento` user? How are you launching it? How did you installed? What version exactly?

Comment: It never runs, so I can't check what user it wants to use. I'm using `sudo service kurento-media-server start` to attempt to start, so I guess it will try to start as `root:root`. I installed KMS using `apt` following the installation guide in the docs. I have 6.4.0 installed.

Comment: Try running `sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start` if you didn't modify anything it should run as user `kurento`. If you still have problems, try deleting `/var/log/kurento-mediaserver` directory completely.

Comment: My mistake, `kurento-media-server-6.0` was the service I was trying to start. Tried deleting `/var/log/kurento-media-server` and running again and the error log is showing the same error. This is really strange- I'm working with our systems engineer and we can't figure out why this isn't working.

Comment: Is there anything in other log files?

Comment: I've edited the response to help others in case someone returns to this question.